# Using variables in pathnames and pathname variable help plus finding username applescript?

Tags: applescript, file, path

So, I want to have my script to be able to find out the current user's username and store it in  a variable (myUsername). Then, it will go to /Users/myUsername/Desktop/FV.app. How can I do this and insert the variable in the file address in order to open the file? Your help is very appreciated! If any clarification is needed, I will reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder" to open ((path to desktop) as text) & "FV.app"
```